# How to add a specific spacing in pixels between tkinter buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have written some code for some buttons. However, I am not sure how to add a specific number of pixels of spacing for each button. So far is the code I have written. However, I have not yet figured out a reliable way to add spacing between the buttons in pixel sizes.

```
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import PhotoImage

def banana():
    print ("Sundae")

def tomato():
    print ("Ketchup")

def potato():
    print ("Potato chips")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=70, height=30)
f1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="we")

button_qwer = tk.Button(f1, text="Banana", command=banana)
button_asdf = tk.Button(f1, text="Tomato", command=tomato)
button_zxcv = tk.Button(f1, text="Potato", command=potato)

button_qwer.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_asdf.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_zxcv.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a specific number of pixels of spacing between each `Button`doesn't sound to me like such as good idea because it isn't very flexible nor easily portable to devices with different resolutions.

Nevertheless I've figured-out a way of doing it—namely by putting a do-nothing invisible button between of the each real ones. This got somewhat involved, mostly because it requires putting an image on each `Button` used this way so its `width` option argument will be interpreted as number of pixels instead of number of characters (here's [some documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/button.html) describing the various `Button` widget configuration options).

```
import tkinter as tk

# Inline XBM format data for a 1x1 pixel image.
BITMAP = """
    #define im_width 1
    #define im_height 1
    static char im_bits[] = {
        0x00
    };
"""

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")
bitmap = tk.BitmapImage(data=BITMAP, maskdata=BITMAP)

f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=70, height=30)
f1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)

def banana():
    print ("Sundae")

def tomato():
    print ("Ketchup")

def potato():
    print ("Potato chips")

def layout_buttons(parent, buttons, spacing):
    if buttons:
        first, *rest = buttons
        first.grid(row=0, column=0)  # Position first Button.

        for index, button in enumerate(rest, start=1):
            col = 2*index
            # Dummy widget to separate each button from the one before it.
            separator = tk.Button(parent, relief=tk.FLAT, state=tk.ACTIVE,
                                  image=bitmap, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                  width=spacing)
            separator.grid(row=0, column=col-1)
            button.grid(row=0, column=col)

buttons = (
    tk.Button(f1, text="Banana", command=banana),
    tk.Button(f1, text="Tomato", command=tomato),
    tk.Button(f1, text="Potato", command=potato),
)

layout_buttons(f1, buttons, 30)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of window with buttons with space between them]

Here's a blow-up showing that the spacing is exactly 30 pixels (as counted in my image editor and indicated by the thin horizontal black line between the adjacent edges of the two `Button`s).

[image: blow-up of previous screenshot]

Comment: How do you add spacing to one side only?

Comment: The spacing feature from the padding with buttons does work, but however I still cannot find an effective way to get the buttons to have a specific amount of spacing to one specific side.

Comment: Sorry, don't know of a way to do that directly. Perhaps you could put blank place-holder `Buttons` (or some other widget) between the real ones.

Comment: Will such blank placeholder buttons be "invisible"? I also tried using blank labels but they simply won't work in my existing code because the labels just simply just go above or below the buttons.

Comment: Instead of an invisible button with an image, a simpler solution is to use an empty `Frame` which can be configure to be a specific width in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Adding space between widgets depends on how you are putting the widgets in the window. Since you are using `grid`, one simple solution is to leave empty columns between the buttons, and then give these columns a `minsize` equal to the space you want.

Example:

```
f1.grid_columnconfigure((1, 3), minsize=10, weight=0)

button_qwer.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_asdf.grid(row=0, column=2)
button_zxcv.grid(row=0, column=4)
```

Comment: Bryan: Ah, yes, sounds much simpler...I was hoping you'd chime in with some useful information or a "trick" to do it... `;¬)`

Comment: What exactly do I have to change my code to make the program look like what you have explained?

Comment: @RonZhang: I don't understand the question. Just replace your existing calls to `grid` with the code in my answer.

Comment: Then what happens to the `f1.grid_columnconfigure((1, 3), minsize=10, weight=0)`? Where does it go in my current program?

Comment: @RonZhang: anywhere you want after creating `f1`